# How do you set the Typescript type for useRef hook in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

How do I correctly type the useRef for a React Native TextInput?
With the below code I get the following error.

> `Property 'isFocused' does not exist on type 'MutableRefObject<TextInput>'`

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const TestScreen = () => {

  const searchInputRef = useRef<TextInput>();

  const updateSearchText = (searchText: string) => {
    console.log(searchTextRef.isFocused()); //   Error here.
  };

  return (
    <TextInput
      ref={searchInputRef}
      placeholder="Search"
      onChangeText={(text: string) => updateSearchText(text)}
      autoCorrect={false}
      autoCapitalize="none"
      value={searchText}
    />
  )

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be

```
 const updateSearchText = (searchText: string) => {
    console.log(searchInputRef.current.isFocused());
  };
```

Comment: Well... that's a little embarrassing.  Thanks!